# T-SQL combine indirectly related tables into single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a parent table called "Businesses" with two different related/child tables (Affiliates and Employees) related to a business but not directly to each other.

I want a single SQL query that will show all businesses, affiliates and employees with one line item for each employee. For example, given business "B1" with 2 Affiliates (A1 and A2) and two Employees (E1 and E2), I want a query with results that look something like:

| Business | Affiliates | Empl # | Empl Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | A1, A2 | 1 | John |
| B1 | A1, A2 | 2 | Bob |

The closest I've gotten is output that looks like:

| Business | Affiliates | Empl # | Empl Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | A1 | 1 | John |
| B1 | A1 | 2 | Bob |
| B1 | A2 | 1 | John |
| B1 | A2 | 2 | Bob |

But as you can see, each employee shows twice (once for each affiliate).

Any suggestions on how to achieve the desired result?

Comment: What version of sql server are you on?

Comment: Also, typically this kind of work is better handled in your client code or reporting tool.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I'm on SQL Server 2016.  Agreed, I could achieve this in client code.  Just trying to get there with t-sql for now.

Comment: Okay, then you have to do it the hard way. My answer requires at least 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this.

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE ( business char(12), affiliates VARCHAR(25), empid int);

INSERT INTO @Sample VALUES
    ( 'B1', 'A1', 50 ),
    ( 'B1', 'A1', 80 ),
    ( 'B1', 'A2', 90 ),
    ( 'B1', 'A2', 50 );
    
SELECT  O.business,
        STUFF( (SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CAST(affiliates AS VARCHAR(25)) 
                FROM @Sample I WHERE I.business = O.business FOR XML PATH('')
                ), 1, 2, '')
FROM    @Sample O
GROUP BY O.business;
```

Result:

[image]

Change to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks @ASH, I applied the same principals as you've described, STUFFing the affiliates into a temporary table using SELECT INTO instead of DECLARE and INSERT.  That did the trick for me.

Comment: Nice! I'm trying to learn SQL better. You can learn a ton by reading posts here, and also by trying to help others solve their problems!

Comment: @rfinn - Just to be clear, it's not the STUFF that does the magic of string concatenation here.  It's the FOR XML PATH that's doing the trick.  STUFF is just being used to get rid of the leading comma in all of that.

Answer (score 1):

With SQL Sever 2017 and later:

```
WITH existing as (

   -- your existing query goes here

) 
SELECT Business, string_agg(Affiliates, ',') as Affiliates,
     [Empl #], MAX([Empl Name]) As [Empl Name]
FROM existing
GROUP BY Business, [Empl #]
```

Comment: Thanks Joel, string_agg looks like what I needed but as you say, SQL Server 2017+ needed.